# Adicionar novo arquivo a commit

Tags: git, commit

Como faço para adicionar novos arquivos a um commit já realizado no Git, sem criar um novo commit?

Caso já tenha realizado o push para o servidor remoto, como "re-commitar"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você deve utilizar o parâmetro `--amend`, **caso seja o último commit**

```
git commit --amend
git add file2.txt
```

E quando for da push utilize:

```
git push --force <repository> <branch>
```

> **Referênca:**
>   https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-commit--amend/

Answer (score 9):

Se fizer `--force`, e outros autores tiverem criado novos commits entretanto, esses commits serão **apagados permanentemente**. `--force` é receita para desastre e deve ser evitado a todo o custo.

`--amend` é recomendado **apenas** se o commit ainda nao tiver sido publicado.

Como neste caso o commit já foi publicado, o melhor é criar mesmo um novo commit com os novos arquivos. [`amend` é reescrever historia, é *mentir* ao git](http://paul.stadig.name/2010/12/thou-shalt-not-lie-git-rebase-ammend.html).